# Extracting fields name from single string using split method

Tags: java, string

I have a string variable that I want to extract some words from. These words are field names that I am going to need.Currently, I'm using the split method to split string into array.

```
String whereClause = "id=? AND name=?";
String[] results = whereClause.split("[=?]");
```

In this case I am only interesting in getting an array containing "id" and "name" but what I'm getting is [id, ,  AND name]. This also gets " " and the word "AND". How can I reconstruct this to accomplish what I'm trying to do or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do matching instead os splitting.

```
String s = "id=? AND name=?";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[^\\s=?]+(?=[=?])").matcher(s);
while(m.find()){
System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

`[^\\s=?]+` matches any character but not of a space or `=` or `?` chars, one or more times.

**Output:**

```
id
name
```

**OR**

Create a new Array list and then append the matched results to that.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
String s = "id=? AND name=?";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[^\\s=?]+(?=[=?])").matcher(s);
while(m.find()){
list.add(m.group());
}
System.out.println(list);
```

Output:

```
[id, name]
```

Comment: How would I accommodate spaces between the field name and =? e.g. id =?

Comment: `"[^\\s=?]+(?=\\s*[=?])"`

Comment: I'm not really good regular expression (don't understand it) I want to modify the one that you gave me to include >? with and without space. I tried "[^\\s=?]+(?=\\s*[=?])|[^\\s>?]+(?=\\s*[>?])" but it didn't work.

Comment: The thing is I'll need to match multiple different case and combinations. Is using this approach the best way?

Comment: @user2054833 i think so. If you still have any doubts then ask it as a new question with a complex example.

Answer (score 0):

```
String whereClause = "id=? AND name=?";
String[] results = whereClause.split("[=?]");
System.out.println(results[0]);
        System.out.println(results[2].substring(results[2].indexOf("AND")+4,results[2].length()));
```

Try this code,i am simply doing substring of the given string

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, you always should provide some explanation for why it does so.

Answer (score 0):

Split with blankspace

```
String whereClause = "id=? AND name=?";
String[] results = whereClause.split(" ");
for(String tempResult : results)
{
    if(tempResul.indexOf("id")=-1)
    {
     // do your logic here
    }
    //same with other name 
}
```